# Ansible AWX docker container infinite restart

Tags: docker, ansible, containers, restart

I have a problem installing Ansible AWX; When I execute the ansible playbook (***ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml***), i have the 5/5 containers there (saw them using ***docker ps -a***). But awx_web and **awx_task** are infinitelly restarting. Any help?

```
[root@CLOUDSVRANSIBLE installer]# docker ps -a
5d132be6d6cd        ansible/awx_task:latest      "/tini -- /bin/sh ..."   8 minutes ago       Restarting (127) About a minute ago                                                         awx_task
cb83308dcfcf        ansible/awx_web:latest       "/tini -- /bin/sh ..."   8 minutes ago       Restarting (127) About a minute ago                                                         awx_web
43b314e42815        postgres:9.6                 "docker-entrypoint..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                          5432/tcp                                              awx_postgres
9c73fd740f98        ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4   "docker-entrypoint..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                          4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671-15672/tcp, 25672/tcp   awx_rabbitmq
8fcbf04c4c96        memcached:alpine             "docker-entrypoint..."   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                          11211/tcp                                             awx_memcached
```

Logs:

```
[root@CLOUDSVRANSIBLE installer]# docker logs awx_task
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh: No such file or directory
...

[root@CLOUDSVRANSIBLE installer]# docker logs awx_web
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/launch_awx.sh: No such file or directory
...
```

[Docker status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uQVd.png)

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer...

It was a ports conflict with nginx.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

It seams to me the installation of AWX did not complete correctly.

What type of installation are you trying? What is the underlying OS?

The task that copies these bash scripts is referenced in the role image_build.

Can you have a look at the output of your playbook to see what is going wrong?
You might need to run it with some -vvvvvv to get some nice info.